# Prevent ODP.net from nationalizing string

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, linq, entity-framework

I'm using ODP.net with EntityFramework 6.
I have a problem with a linq request with a big where clause.

```
var preResult = _context.table1.Where(item => item.natid != 7).Where(inc => inc.nat.Name.Contains(searchValue)
                || inc.Datedet.ToString("dd/MM/yyy").Contains(searchValue)
                ... (omited for brievity)
                || inc.nb.ToString().Contains(searchValue)
                ).Skip(start).Take(length);
```

The problem is that the generated query fail with a ORA-12704: character set mismatch, due to this :

```
...((((CASE WHEN ("Extent4"."YYYY" IS NULL) THEN N'' ELSE "Extent4"."ZZZZ" END)||(' - ')))||(CASE WHEN ("Extent4"."XXXX" IS NULL) THEN N'' ELSE "Extent4"."XXXX" END)) AS "C2",...
```

If i replace the **N''** by just **''**, the request woks and return the good results.

My current solution is to use a IDbCommandInterceptor to make a global replace like the above with *ReaderExecuting* but I think this is a bit extreme.

Do you have a better solution ?

Comment: Use a sane ORM instead of EF (like [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net))

Comment: Sorry, but my project DAL are already heavily based on EF, and I really, really want to keep the linq querying method (as it seem drapper only provide a pseudo sql syntax). Also, draper seam to be an **OM**, without the relationship and navigational property part.

Answer (score 1):

By default, entity properties of type string will map to the national character set.

You can reconfigure that behavior per property. That should solve your problem.

See this link for more info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617#1.9

Copy-paste of the interesting part:

> **Configuring whether a String Property Supports Unicode Content**
>
> By default strings are Unicode (nvarchar in SQL Server). You can use the IsUnicode method to specify that a string should be of varchar type.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Department>()
    .Property(t => t.Name)
    .IsUnicode(false);
```

Comment: I'm using the designer to build my model, so I will look for the equivalent in it, thanks

Comment: If this was helpful to you, an accepted answer is always appreciated :)

Comment: Sadly it didn't fix my problem as it seem either EF or ODP use a N'' empty string when needing to concat multiple nullable field, so even by forcing those fields as unicode (or as non unicode) in the designer, the problem still occur.

Comment: Sorry to hear that :(

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem and there is two solutions:

- You can add EntityFunctions.AsNonUnicode() in your query : 
  `inc.nat.Name.Contains(EntityFunctions.AsNonUnicode(searchValue))`

It will force odp.net to use non unicode characters

- Update yous oracle provider, odac 12c fix this problem : https://community.oracle.com/message/11065799#11065799

Comment: I'm already with the lastest 12c ODAC, but I will test your solution, thanks